# Configuring service restart with 'restart service after' parameter

Tags: windows-service

It appears that sc.exe isn't capable of setting the 'restart service after' parameter and powershell isn't capable of setting up service restarts at all.

My intended configuration is failure1/restart failure2/restart failure3/nothing with a five minute counter between each restart. The five minute timer is extremely important.

Is there anything else I can look at other than some registry hackery configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure response is stored in the `REG_BINARY` value `FailureActions` under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\<SERVICE_NAME>`.  You'll probably have to set it the way you want it on one machine using `services.msc`, grab the data from the `FailureActions` value in the Registry, and then script the configuration with `reg add` (or `reg import` if using a .REG file).

Comment: Good answer. That is about what I did, with the exception of creating a script that lets me do this to arbitrary combinations of hosts and services.